# How can I avoid having to reload my environment?

Tags: environment-variables

I'm not sure why, but I keep having to type 'source /etc/environment' in order for my path to be updated correctly. I don't want to type this inside of my bashrc, since I don't want it related to that. This is for a server, and I want to make sure that the environment settings stick.

Thank you

Comment: Can you give a little more information regarding context?

Comment: What OS is on the server (if Linux, what distribution)? The standard location for environment variables is `/etc/profile` (system-wide) and `~/.profile` (per-user). `/etc/environment` is an additiona file used on some distributions.

Comment: @Gilles I believe /etc/environment is the preferred location for system-wide environment variables in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your shell is, but generally I would place this in my `.profile`